# Shift Report for Week / Month for a particular shift in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my UI, I have two filters:

```
Date - Today , Yesterday, WTD , MTD
Shift - 1st, 2nd, 3rd
```

Shift timings are following:

```
1st: 06:00 - 14:00
2nd: 14:00 - 22:00
3rd: 22:00 - 06:00
```

I am counting production qualtities for each material via following query:

```
SELECT 
       C.MATERIAL
      ,G.MACHINE
      ,F.PART   
      ,SUM(A.QT_CONFIRMED) QT_CONFIRMED

 FROM 
       CONFIRMATION A 

       INNER JOIN LOT_RECORD B ON A.LOT_RECORD_ID=B.LOT_RECORD_ID
       INNER JOIN LOT C ON B.LOT_RECORD_ID=C.LOT_RECORD_ID
       INNER JOIN MATERIAL D ON C.MATERIAL = D.MATERIAL
       INNER JOIN PART F ON C.PART=F.PART
       INNER JOIN MACHINE G ON F.MACHINE=G.MACHINE

WHERE
      A.DT_CONFIRMATION BETWEEN '[Param.1]' AND '[Param.2]'

GROUP BY
       C.MATERIAL
      ,G.MACHINE
      ,F.PART

ORDER BY 
       G.MACHINE ASC
```

For Today / Yesterday, I can get the date and shift and can pass relevant parameter to the query and getting proper output.

Like if I select Yesterday and Choose shift 2nd then

```
Param.1 = 2015-12-14T14:00:00 
Param.2 = 2015-12-14T22:00:00
```

But problem I'm facing is for WTD and MTD. If I choose MTD and 1st shift then

My Start date will be 1st Dec. End Date will be 15th Dec.
Now I can't pass

```
Param.1 = 2015-12-01T06:00:00
Param.2 = 2015-12-15T14:00:00
```

Because it will calculate quantity for all the shifts. I need to pass parameter in such a way that it calulates quantity only between 06:00 - 14:00 for 1st Dec to 15th Dec.

```
Also, for 3rd shift the time will be 10 PM of the start date and 6 AM of startdtae + 1.
```

How can I achieve that? I'm really confused and stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DATEPART()` function in SQL to add another condition that checks that the hour of the `DT_CONFIRMATION` column is within the hours of the shift you are filtering on.

So if you were searching for only `Shift 1`, you would add:

```
AND DATEPART(hour, DT_CONFIRMATION) BETWEEN 6 AND 14
```

to your `WHERE` clause.   You will obviously need to parameterize the WHERE clause with hours based on the Shift, the same as you have done with the dates.

Comment: ok thanks. ANd how about for 3rs shift - can you please show mw psuedo where clause for all 3 shifts?

Comment: For 3rd shift:  `(DATEPART(...) BETWEEN 22 AND 23 OR DATEPART(...) BETWEEN 0 AND 6)`   Or another way:  `AND DATEPART(...) NOT BETWEEN 7 AND 21`